# Can SARS-CoV-2 be a potential cause for Guillain-Barré syndrome?

Tags: covid-19, autoimmune-disease, coronavirus, sars-cov-2

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillain%E2%80%93Barr%C3%A9_syndrome?wprov=sfla1) :-

> ...Although the cause is unknown, the underlying mechanism involves an autoimmune disorder in which the body's immune system mistakenly attacks the peripheral nerves and damages their myelin insulation. Sometimes this immune dysfunction is triggered by an infection or, less commonly by surgery and rarely by vaccination. The diagnosis is usually made based on the signs and symptoms, through the exclusion of alternative causes...

Can the SARS-CoV-2, which causes both upper and lower respiratory tract infections, cause GB syndrome? 
There's evidence that the Zika virus, H1N1 and few other viruses can cause GB Syndrome. Is there any possibility or evidence that the said coronavirus can trigger this autoimmune disease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Like everything else, we're instructed by past experiences. Although there weren't a lot of data on neurologic aspects of MERS and SARS, there were some papers describing neurologic complications in those patients. In rare cases, complications including ADEM (acute disseminated encephalomyelitis)-like demyelination, encephalitis, and brainstem encephalitis were reported. They also saw some peripheral and non–central nervous system stuff, including things that looked like Guillain-Barré syndrome or what they would sometimes call critical illness polyneuropathy

https://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/927562

So, yes, severely affected covid-19 patients may develop something that looks like GBS.